# GWT PHP get Data from Webserver

Tags: php, gwt, webserver

I have a Webpage with a MYSQL Database.
I can easily Insert data in it but when it comes to "Select"
it throws "("Couldn't retrieve JSON")" is it even possbile to get this data from a Webserver with the jetty Server. I acually plan to use Phonegap which supports PHP 
http://phonegap.com/2012/05/02/phonegap-explained-visually/

```
       RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST,URL.encode("http://testeddd.com/test.php"));

   String name = mioUsername.getText();
String pssw = miaPassword.getText();
        JSONObject jsonValue = new JSONObject();
        jsonValue.put("myusername", new JSONString(name));
        jsonValue.put("mypassword", new JSONString(pssw));
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        try {
request.sendRequest(jsonValue.toString(),new RequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
 if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                                      try {
                            JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parse(response.getText());
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonValue.isArray();
                            if (jsonArray != null) {

                                RootPanel.get().clear();
                                  RootPanel.get().add(new MapComp());

                        } else {
                             Dialogs.alert("1", "fault", null);

                        }     } catch (JSONException e) {
                             Dialogs.alert("2",  e.toString(), null);
                          }
                        } else {
                             Dialogs.alert("request none",  "Couldn't retrieve JSON (" + response.getStatusText() + ")", null);
                        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        //displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
    }
});
} catch (com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

my php file:

```
     <?php

  header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  $str = $_POST['param'];
  $con=mysqli_connect("llxxllxxx","lll","lll","lll");
  // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM xxx".$str);

   $i = 0; 
         while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) 
         { 
             $array[$i] = $row; 
             $i++; 
         } 
         $result->close(); 
         $con->close(); 

      print json_encode($array); 




?>
```

Comment: Which exception is thrown? 'displayError(exception.getMessage());'

Comment: Dialogs.alert("request none",  "Couldn't retrieve JSON (" + response.getStatusText() + ")", null);
<-- is always thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) or the [domain whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_whitelist_index.md.html).

If you load a page from one domain (or same domain and different port / protocol) the browser will send the request, but don't deliver the answer too your javascript.

It will be the statuscode 0 and an empty message.

To send [CORS-Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) may also help.

Comment: dang i thought :   builder.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");, would be enough, could u help me?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you should `URL.encode` the entire URL.

URL encoding the entire URL will result in `http://testeddd.com/test.php` becoming `http%3A%2F%2Ftesteddd.com%2Ftest.php`

Comment: Sorry: I was unclear. I meant you should remove the `URL.encode`. Not that you should switch the url, if that's what your did.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the question properly. I will look further into it.

Comment: Okay, so you don't get the 200 statusCode from PHP. What output do you get if you just run the PHP file?

Comment: Also try `header('Content-Type: text/json');`

Comment: What do you get if you change the error message to `Dialogs.alert("request none", "Couldn't retrieve JSON (" + response.getStatusCode() + ")", null);`